# Why is this if statement causing issues in this JS code?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I currently have a discord.js bot running on my server from [this tutorial](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#listening-for-messages). However, when I put the if statement for listening for messages in, the node.js refuses to start it. Said if statement:

```
if (message.content === '!ping') {
    message.channel.send('Pong.');
}
```

edit:

full code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('login token AAAAA');

client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);
});
if (message.content === '!ping') {
    message.channel.send('Pong.');
}
```

error thrown

```
if (message.content === '!ping') {
^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\epopova1\Desktop\poserBot\index.js:13:1)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47[39m
```

sorry for the bad question, I am completely new here

Comment: You should add the complete error trackback for better answers

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting when you execute the code?

Comment: if message is null then you will get an error, try if (message != null && message.content === '!ping')

Comment: Post the full code, along with the error you're getting and the version of discord.js you're using.

Comment: @user13604060 If that's your full code, where is that `if` statement? P.S.: Maybe don't publish your login token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `if` statement inside the `message` event handler, like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('login token AAAAA');

client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    }
});
```